# Java Selenium Automation Chrome close before all tests complete

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

I'm currently doing UI automation using Java Selenium, there I have 3 test classes. When I run them separately I don't encounter any problems. However if I run all 3 pages togather then some test fails saying they cant find the locator. How to solve this issue. Is this an issue with synchronization or is my waiting times could be too long?

```
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:230)
    at pages.CartPage.addItemsToCart(CartPage.java:37)
    at tests.CartPageTest.updateCart(CartPageTest.java:27)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The exception clearly points to the Timeout Exception, add a Wait mechanism after every test.

**@Test**
Test1()
{
//code
Wait<Webdriver> wait=new WebdriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("pass the element it take a time to appear in the page"));
}

**@Test**
Test2()
//your code
Wait<Webdriver> wait=new WebdriverWait(driver, Duration.of seconds(20));

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("pass the element it take a time to appear in the page"));

}
```

**And for the closing browser, have a look into your afterTest or you can remove the closing browser code.**

Comment: Thankyou for the answer .I have actually added them. All my test cases work fine tif I run them individually. But if I run all test classes together as a suit in "testng.xml" then I encounter issues like not find locators, the driver is null etc.